# Using dictionary to convert string to char

Tags: c#

I've got this code:

```
 static string WordMap(string value)
      {
           var strings = value
               .Select(c =>
               {
                   string word;
                   if (!wordMap.TryGetValue(c, out word))
                       word = c.ToString();
                   return word;
               });
           return string.Join("", strings);
       }
```

And a dictionary which looks like this:

```
static Dictionary<char, string> wordMap = new Dictionary<char, string>()
{
   {'a', "Alpha"}...
}
```

Instead of turning the char into words, I want to do the opposite.

I saw there was confusion about what I meant so:

```
// I want this 
input = alpha beta gamma delta
output = abgd
// I get this
input = alpha beta gamma delta
output = alpha lama python hexa alpha...
```

Comment: use string.ToCharArray()

Comment: Do you mean something like turning "Alpha Delta Charlie" to "adc"? Please include example inputs and outputs to clarify your question.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a `Dictionary` is for.

Comment: Please, provide Inputs and expected outputs of: [what you have] and [what you want].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is reverse the mapping back from string to char. This assumes you've already done the work for

```
static Dictionary<char, string> wordMap = new Dictionary<char, string>()
{
    {'a', "Alpha"}...
}
```

So we make a new mapping for the other direction:

```
static Dictionary<string, char> charMap;

public static void ConvertLookup ()
{
    charMap = wordMap.ToDictionary(e => e.Value, e => e.Key);
}
```

One thing this assumes, however, is that your strings are unique.

EDIt: So, taking this a little further, it was my understanding that you wanted to go both ways. So we can put it all together and get something like this:

```
    static Dictionary<char, string> wordMap = new Dictionary<char, string>();
    static Dictionary<string, char> charMap = new Dictionary<string, char>();

    public static void InitializeLookups()
    {
        wordMap = new Dictionary<char, string>
        {
            { 'A', "Alice" },
            { 'B', "Bob" },
            { 'C', "Charlie" }
        };

        charMap = wordMap.ToDictionary(e => e.Value, e => e.Key);
    }

    public static string ConvertCharToWords(string chars)
    {
        var strings = chars
              .Select(c =>
              {
                  string word;
                  if (!wordMap.TryGetValue(c, out word))
                      word = c.ToString();
                  return word;
              });
        return string.Join(" ", strings);
    }
    public static string ConvertWordsToChars(string words)
    {
        var strings = words.Split(' ')
              .Select(c =>
              {
                  char character;
                  if (!charMap.TryGetValue(c, out character))
                      character = '?';
                  return character;
              });
        return string.Join("", strings);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeLookups();
        string words = ConvertCharToWords("ABC");
        string chars = ConvertWordsToChars(words);

        Console.WriteLine(words);
        Console.WriteLine(chars);
    }
```

Input:

```
ABC
```

Output:

```
Alice Bob Charlie
ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it backwards.

```
static Dictionary<string, char> Mapword = new Dictionary<string, char>()
{
   {"Alpha", 'a'}...
}
```

Comment: The dictionary is about 500 times of {'a', alpha} with a different letter and symbol every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<char, string> wordMap = new Dictionary<char, string>()
            {
                {'a', "Alpha"},
                {'b', "Beta"},
                {'d', "Dalta"},
                {'g', "Gama"},
            };
 var input = "Alpha Beta Gama Dalta";

 var output = input.Split()
                    .Select(word => wordMap.Where(x => x.Value == word)
                    .Select(x => x.Key).First());
 var result = string.Join("", output);
 Console.WriteLine(result);

// Output:
// abgd
```