# How to convert a string to a char (to a string)

Tags: c#

I hope the title didn't confuse you too much. this is what I'm trying to get :

```
static Dictionary<string, char> charMap = new Dictionary<string, char>()
       {
           {"alpha ", 'a'},{"beta ",'Y'},{"gamma ", 'g'},{"delta", '='}
       };

       static string CharMap(string value)
       {
           var strings = value
               .Select(c =>
               {
                   string letter;
                   if (!charMap.TryGetValue(the, out letter))
                       letter = c.ToString();
                   return letter;
               });
           return string.Join("", strings);
       }
```

I want this to to this :

Input - alpha beta gamma delta

Output - aYg=

How can i get this code to work?

Comment: You don't need `letter = c.ToString()`.  The `out` param sets the variable `letter` already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using dictionary to convert string to char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486563/using-dictionary-to-convert-string-to-char)

Comment: Are you sure code and input/output match? looks like code is for opposite conversion ( a -> alpha...)

Comment: yes the input/output match, i already made this in another part and now i need a piece of code which does the opposite and i got trouble doing it.

Comment: So why dont you actually use the greek characters? They work in C# too, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var stringToSearch =  value.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
 var Result = string.Concat( charMap.Where(o => stringToSearch.Contains(o.Key)).ToList().Select(a => a.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static Dictionary<string, char> charMap = new Dictionary<string, char>()
   {
        {"alpha", 'a'}, {"beta", 'Y'}, {"gamma", 'g'}, {"delta", '='}
   };

void Main()
{
    var input = "alpha beta gamma delta";

    var result = CharMap(input);
}

public string CharMap(string input)
{
    var result = "";

    foreach (var item in input.Split(' '))
    {
        result += charMap[item];    
    }

    return result;
}
```

result:

> aYg=

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regular expression, like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> charMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   {"alpha", "a"},{"beta","Y"},{"gamma", "g"},{"delta", "="}
};

static string CharMap(string value)
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"(\w+)\s*", m => {
        string result;
        charMap.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out result);
        return result ?? m.Groups[1].Value;
    });
}

Console.WriteLine(CharMap("alpha beta gamma delta")); // aYg=
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to split you string coming in. Also just += (concat) the char with the string and you should be good.

```
   static Dictionary<string, char> charMap = new Dictionary<string, char>()
   {
       {"alpha ", 'a'},{"beta ",'Y'},{"gamma ", 'g'},{"delta", '='}
   };

   static string CharMap(string value)
   {

        string [] split = value.Split(new Char [] {' '});
        string entireString = string.Empty;
        for(string str in split)
    {
        char letter;
        if (charMap.TryGetValue(the, out letter))
        entireString += letter;
    }
        return entireString;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like,

```
static string CharMap(string value)
{
    char l;
    return string.Join(
        string.Empty, 
        value.Split(' ').Select(v => charMap.TryGetValue(v, out l) ? l.ToString() : string.Empty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You already asked this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486563/using-dictionary-to-convert-string-to-char). The code I posted for you earlier works perfectly.

However, take a look at your inputs you gave here:

```
{"alpha ", 'a'},{"beta ",'Y'},{"gamma ", 'g'},{"delta", '='}
```

Notice that you've got **SPACES** at the end of each of your keys. `"alpha{SPACE}"`

Change it to:

```
{"alpha", 'a'},{"beta",'Y'},{"gamma", 'g'},{"delta", '='}
```

EDIT: Full code in fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/VDn0mD

Output:

> aYg=

Comment: @rae1 - nope, quote: "But instead of turning the char to words, I want to do the opposite." - same question in both places.

Comment: The question you mentioned is converting "char to words"; this question is converting "words to chars". Not that it is a big diff...

Comment: Nope, reread it and differentiate between his "what I have" and his "what I want".

Answer (score 0):

This meant to be a comment on Vlad Bezden's post, but I do not yet have 50 reputation.

This should appears to be what the OP asked for:

Input => "alpha beta gamma delta"

Output => "aYg"

The OP appears to be splitting the input string by all characters using the LINQ on the String as a collection, hence:

"alpha beta gamma delta" becomes 'a','l','p','h','a',' ', etc...

If the OP wants the reverse of the above function:

Input => "aYg"
Output => "alpha beta gamma delta"

For simplicity you should create the reverse dictionary and look up the values from there, because the values could collide.